# How to format the json Date format using spring boot and spring hateoas

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am working on spring boot and spring hateoas for creating a rest api.
I need to format the date format to "yyyy-MM-dd".

I do not want to make use of @JsonFormat, because this annotation has to be used everywhere we use a Date.

So kindly help me out to achieve this configuration globally, instead of making use of @JsonFormat everywhere.

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting and removed irrelevant thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) If you're using jackson, you can set the date format globally by setting the following value in your application.properties/application.yml:

```
spring.jackson.date-format= # Date format string (e.g. yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss), or a fully-qualified date format class name (e.g. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat)
```